# Why I’m getting overlaps with fast Ethernet 0/1 when assigning an ip

Tags: cisco, router, rip, errors

[image]

But I have been receiving error code when I want to assist an ip to s1/0

Answer (score 4):

You can't have two interfaces on the same subnet.  In your case, you're trying to put both on 192.168.10.0/24.  You'll have to choose a different subnet for one of them.